# Using template programming to change the type of the container

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have been reading through a template metaprogramming tutorial and I am struck at this example from that book.

```
 /* Change the type container */
  template<class NewList, class List>
  struct rename_container;
  
  template<template<class...> class NewList,
           template<class...> class List,
           class... Elements>
  struct rename_container<NewList, List<Elements...>>
  {
      using new_list = NewList<Elements...>;
  };

  int main()
  {
      rename_container<std::variant, std::tuple<int, float, double>> v;
      return 0;
  }
```

I am getting the following error among other errors.

```
type_containers.cpp:52:50: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class NewList, class List> struct rename_container’
 struct rename_container<NewList, List<Elements...>>
                                                  ^~
type_containers.cpp:52:50: note:   expected a type, got ‘NewList’
```

Can someone help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: The primary template `rename_container` expects two type parameters, but the specialization attempts to use a template parameter. That can't work. I'm not sure what this example is supposed to achieve, it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: You want `template<template<class...> class NewList, class List> struct rename_container;` for the primary template.

Comment: You might have meant something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/KeTeTo). Sill looks pretty pointless, but at least it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is a typo, it should be

```
/* Change the type container */
  template<template<class...> class NewList, class List>
  struct rename_container;
```

and probably:

```
rename_container<std::variant, std::tuple<int, float, double>>::new_list v;
// v is std::variant<int, float, double>
```

Comment: okay. That worked. Looks like it is a typo in the book itself that I was following. I have a question. Why is it template<template<class...> class NewList, class List> instead of template<template<class...> class NewList, template<class...> class List>? As in the case of the secondary template?

Comment: Why is template<class...> repeated only once in the primary template?

Comment: If you look at usage, second parameter is `std::tuple<int, float, double>` which is a type contrary to just `std::tuple` or `std::variant`.